# Customise DatePicker to show only day and month SwiftUI

Tags: date, swiftui, datepicker

I need to implement DatePicker View. However, instead of using standard month/day/year, I have to make day/month.
I've been searching for hours, but still found nothing.
Thanks for your attention.
[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUfEv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove the year from the `DatePicker`. However, you can create a custom date picker using a `Picker` view or you can use a date range on the `DatePicker` to limit the date to the start and end of the current year. Here's a sample of the latter

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var date = Date()
  let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()
    var startComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
    startComponents.day = 1
    startComponents.month = 1
    var endComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
    endComponents.day = 31
    endComponents.month = 12
    return calendar.date(from:startComponents)!
    ...
    calendar.date(from:endComponents)!
  }()
  
  
  var body: some View {
    DatePicker("Date",
               selection: $date,
               in: dateRange,
               displayedComponents: [.date])
  }
}
```

Note that the year still appears but it is locked down to the current year.

Comment: Thank you! It's a nice idea, but, unfortunately, I need only day/month cause of design.

Comment: Then go with option one, build a custom picker.